# Is there any difference between using "true" and True in PySpark Load/Save functions?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have seen people using them interchangeably, and in the Spark documentation, they are also using both of them.

- Example from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html (using string of true)

  df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv",
  format="csv", sep=";", inferSchema="true", header="true")
- Example from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html (using True as boolean)

  df3 = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").option("header", True).csv(path)

Hence, it came to my mind when I try to align my code. Is there any significant difference (e.g., performance, etc.) between using "true"/"false" and True/False?

Comment: What does the doc say about acceptable values for those parameters? If they are meant to be bools, it's possible that "false" doesn't do what you think at all.

Comment: both of them are acceptable, and are evaluated equally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation of the option and options methods from the **DataFrameReader** class :

```
     def option(key : scala.Predef.String, value : scala.Predef.String) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = { /* compiled code */ }
     def option(key : scala.Predef.String, value : scala.Boolean) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = { /* compiled code */ }
     def option(key : scala.Predef.String, value : scala.Long) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = { /* compiled code */ }
     def option(key : scala.Predef.String, value : scala.Double) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = { /* compiled code */ }
     def options(options : scala.collection.Map[scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String]) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = { /* compiled code */ }
     def options(options : java.util.Map[scala.Predef.String, scala.Predef.String]) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = { /* compiled code */ }
```

As you can see, for the option method, the key must be a String and the value may be a String, Boolean, Long or Double
For the options method, It takes a Map[String, String]

So, doing

```
option("header", "true")
//or
option("header, true)
```

will do the same

Comment: Thanks. I tested it out after accepting and upvoting, and found that it seems options can also take boolean as their values.

There are also some examples out there using boolean (https://dbmstutorials.com/pyspark/spark-read-write-dataframe-options.html)

e.g., `df=spark.read.options(header=True, delimiter="|").csv("file:///path_to_file/tutorial_file_with_header.txt")`


I checked the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#options-scala.collection.Map-) but it's just as you mention so I am still wondering